# How to implement custom fetch hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I try to implement my custom hook in my module . But its shows that I violate some hooks rules

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import useFetch from '../../Helpers/Custom useFetch()';

import MedicineList from './MedicineUI';

const MedicineContainer = () => {
  const [medicineLists, setMedicineList] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/medicines')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((medicineList) => {


        setMedicineList(medicineList);
      });
  }, []);
  return <MedicineList medicineList={medicineLists} />;
};
const res = useFetch('http://localhost:5000/api/medicines', {});


export default MedicineContainer;
```

custom fetch code is given below

```
   import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useFetch = (url, options) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [options, url]);
  return { response, error, isLoading };
};
export default useFetch;
```

suggest me if any modification required in useFetch custom hooks

Comment: what the meaning of `const [apiResult, setApiResult] = useFetch([])`? is that the usage cause the error?

Comment: @HagaiHarari thats is not required.

Answer (score 0):

- you are trying to call useFetch outside of MedicineContainer

```
const res = useFetch('http://localhost:5000/api/medicines', {});
console.log(res, 'popopo');
```

- Your usage of useFetch is incorrect inside MedicineContainer. You need to call it with url and options and use the returned value instead of maintain a state again

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import useFetch from '../../Helpers/Custom useFetch()';

import MedicineList from './MedicineUI';

const MedicineContainer = ( ) => {

  const { response, error, loading } = useFetch('http://localhost:5000/api/medicines',  { } );

  if ( loading ) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
  return <MedicineList medicineList={response} />;
};


export default MedicineContainer;
```

Comment: ×
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: Did you remove the usage of useFetch from outside of MedicineContainer?

Comment: Any suggestion or modifications required for custom hooks?

Comment: Your custom hook was correct, its only the usage which was wrong